# Nautilus cannot open password-protected .rar File

Tags: nautilus, password, 22.04, rar

I use Ubuntu 22.04 and I have installed `sudo apt install unrar`. But if I want to open a password protected .rar file in Nautilus with `Extract here...` then it should ask me the password, but instead the error `There was an error extracting name.rar` and `Block checksum error: got Oxe3, expected 0x71` pops up.

- If I open it via a terminal with `unrar e name.rar` it works perfectly.
- If I double click the name.rar then it opens a window and I am asked to give the password and I can nicely extract the content

In 20.04 this works fine.

What can I do? Is that a bug or my installation?

Comment: You can report a bug.

Comment: How do I report a bug?

Comment: Run `ubuntu-bug file-roller` and follow directions.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it.